# Limit of $\frac{1}{x+i y}$ for $y \rightarrow 0$ and distributional relations

Tags: limits, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

So I know for $y \rightarrow 0$ I have the following (distrubutional) relation:

$\frac{1}{x+i y} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} - i \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} = P(1/x) - i \pi \delta(x) $

where in the last expression the limit was taken, $P$ denotes Cauchy prinzipal value and $\delta$ the Dirac-delta distribution.

Now, I would like to take the limit $y \rightarrow 0$ of the expression $\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{z+i y}}$ . Having not dealt with limits in a long time, can you guys estimate if this is possible? Maybe even ideas on how to go about this?

***edit**

The original question in proper notation:

Let $x_1,x_2 \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R} $, $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\varepsilon > 0$.

What happens to the expression $\frac{1}{x+x_1+\frac{1}{x+x_2 \pm i \varepsilon}}$ for $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ for a given $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of the answer depends on the allowed values for the parameters involved.

If $x=0$, the expression can be rewritten as $z+iy$, which tends to $z$ as $y\to0$.

Suppose $x\neq0$ and
let $z=u+iv$,
$$
\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{z+iy}}=\frac{u+i\left(y+v\right)}{\left(1+xu\right)+ix\left(y+v\right)}.
$$
If $v\neq0$, as $y\to0$, we get
$$
\frac{u+iy}{\left(1+xu\right)+ix}
$$
If $v=0$, let also $y=\pm\varepsilon,$ for positive $\varepsilon$,
$$
\frac{u\pm i\varepsilon}{\left(1+xu\right)\pm ix\varepsilon} \rightarrow u \left[PV\left(\frac{1}{1+xu}\right)\mp i\pi\delta(1+xu) \right].
$$

Comment: You're right I'm sorry for not clearifying that. $x,z$ can be assumed real. It's also needed tp consider $y = \pm \varepsilon$. Thus you're last expression seems relevant to my case.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+iy}}=\frac{x+iy}{1+x(x+iy)}=\frac{x+iy}{1+x^{2}+ixy}
\rightarrow \frac{x}{1+x^{2}}
\end{equation*}
Edit

For the correct expression for general $z$
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{z+iy}}=\frac{z+iy}{1+x(z+iy)}\overset{y\rightarrow 0}{%
\longrightarrow }\frac{z}{1+xz}
\end{equation*}
Distributions do not seem to come into play.

Comment: Please note the $z$ in $\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{z+i y}}$. Also I would expect a non vanishing imaginary part (something like a delta distribution).

Comment: I thought it was an $x$. The letters on the web page are so tiny that I misread them. Sorry. I will have a second look.

Comment: See the edit in my answer

Comment: There is a problem though for specific values of $x,z$. Suppose $x=-\frac{1}{z}$. Taking the limit then gives you $\infty$ instead of $0$ for the imaginary part.

Comment: I took it that $x$ is real and $z$ a general complex variable. As a function of complex $z$ there is indeed a pole for $z=-x^{-1}$. In the original equation it is located at ${x^{-1}}-iy$, which looks consistent. What is your ultimate aim?

Comment: I see, should have used a better notation in hindsight. Ultimativley I want to know what happens if one considers continued fractions of this form.